# Regular expression for string did not work

Tags: php, regex

I have following strings. I want to extract part of it using regular expression.

```
TW - 5657980 Due Date updated :  to <strong>2017-08-13 10:21:00</strong> by <strong>System</strong> 
TW - 5657980 Priority updated  from <strong> Medium</strong> to <strong>Low</strong> by <strong>System</strong> 
TW - 5657980 Material added: <strong>1000 : Cash in Bank - Operating (Old)/ QTY:2</strong> by <strong>System</strong>#9243  
TW - 5657980 Labor added <strong>Kelsey Franks / 14:00 hours </strong> by <strong>System</strong>#65197

Expected result
---------------
Due date updated
Priority updated 
material added
labor added
```

I tried following regular expression.

```
[\s](Due Date|Priority|Material|Labor)\w+
```

but it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing whitespace between your keywords and next word. Also you don't need to match a space before your keywords.

You may use this regex:

```
\b(?:Due Date|Priority|Material|Labor)\h+\w+
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kPJFr9/1)

Note `\h+` before `\w+` to match one or more space or tab characters and `\b` before keywords for word boundary.

Comment: let me try it. Thanks.